# Is it possible to achieve sum of multiple fields using group by in spring data query methods?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I've a table given below

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_horses` (
  `serial_no` BIGINT (5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `horse_id` BIGINT (3) NOT NULL,
  `point` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`serial_no`)
) ;
```

Can I achieve output I'm getting through the following query

```
SELECT 
  th.`horse_id`,
  AVG(th.point)
FROM
  `tbl_horses` th 
GROUP BY (`horse_id`) ;
```

The structure of model is given below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_horses")
public class Horse {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "serial_no")
    private long serialNo;

    @Column(name = "horse_id")
    private long horseId;

    @Column(name = "point")
    private double point;

    public long getSerialNo() {
        return serialNo;
    }

    public void setSerialNo(long serialNo) {
        this.serialNo = serialNo;
    }

    public long getHorseId() {
        return horseId;
    }

    public void setHorseId(long horseId) {
        this.horseId = horseId;
    }

    public double getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    public void setPoint(double point) {
        this.point = point;
    }

}
```

How can I get the result of above query through spring data query methods?
I don't want to use criteria builder over here or native query to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly. You can write these queries using the @Query annotation.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Horse , Long> {

    @Query("SELECT AVG(th.point) from Horse th GROUP BY (th.horseId)")
    int getAverageAge();

}
```

Comment: I'm actually wanting to get the result via method name, that we can do in spring data jpa. The process you are suggesting is native query based.

Comment: @Subha Bhowmik function name is not supported keywords inside method names  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation